# How to avoid an attribute without passing it to post in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic

I am developing rails application. I have a check box in the form like:

```
<td><%= b.check_box :chkbx, label: false, checked: false %></td>
```

While submitting the form. I need to avoid passing checkbox name argument in the post.

How to avoid checkbox attribute from passing it to post in formtastic?

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send the value of the checkbox when the form is submited, you must disable the checkbox before the form is submited.

For example, with jQuery, you can do something like (adapt it to your code)

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#check_box_false').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

If you can, another solution is to put the checkbox outside the `<form>...</form>` tag.